# Extracting tilted recangle using OpenCV after being thresholded

Tags: opencv

After converting to hsv color space thresholding I am left with this, I need to extract the big rectangle in the middle.

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the 4 points like this:

[image]

most likely we'll need to detect the contours of the image. As there is one shape that is larger than the shape you want to get the points of, we'll need to detect the contours with the second greatest area.

We can do this by getting all the contours in the form of a list, sorting the list of contours by their area using the `cv2.contourArea` method as the key for the built-in `sorted` method, we can index the next to the last contour in the sorted list.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (7, 7), 3)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 50, 50)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=3)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=3)
    return img_erode

def get_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-2]
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.03 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2) 

img = cv2.imread("image.png") # Replace with your hsv image
get_contours(img)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Why are you doing BGR2GRAY the image is only one channel?

Comment: @MuhammadElnimr I don't have access to your array; I had to save the image to my pc, and reading it into my program gave me a BGR image.

Comment: I understand now. The funny thing is if I access the thresholded image directly it behaves differently than if it gets saved to disk and read again like you did.